# How to convert camel case format my data?

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I am executiong sql queries from different data sources. And I am getting the results as dynamic objects like following.

```
    private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> GetDataFromPostgresql()
    {
        var dataList = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

        IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();

        obj.Add("first_name", "john");
        obj.Add("last_name", "smith");
        obj.Add("age", 25);

        dataList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>(obj));
        return dataList;
    }

    private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> GetDataFromOracle()
    {
        var dataList = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

        IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();

        obj.Add("FIRST_NAME", "john");
        obj.Add("LAST_NAME", "smith");
        obj.Add("AGE", 25);

        dataList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>(obj));
        return dataList;
    }

    private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> GetDataFromMssql()
    {
        var dataList = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

        IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();

        obj.Add("FirstName", "john");
        obj.Add("LastName", "smith");
        obj.Add("Age", 25);

        dataList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>(obj));
        return dataList;
    }
```

I am using these data collections in my asp.net core controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public  IActionResult Get()
    {
        var dataList = GetDataFromPostgresql();

        return Ok(dataList);
    }
```

But I want to serialize responses a standart camel case format.

```
{ "firstName": "john", "lastName": "smith", "age": 25 }
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

*PascalCase* means it has a capitalized first letter, but if this kind of outcome that you are after, `{ "firstName": "john", "lastName": "smith", "age": 25 }`, that's called [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

I am not familiar with nowadays asp.net-core, but I am sure the RegExp would be the same as this JavaScript one.

```
function toUpperCase(raw, letter) {
  return letter.toUpperCase();
}

function asCamelCase(str) {
            // put an underscore between camel cases
  return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2')
            // make the whole string lower case
            .toLowerCase()
            // capitalize every letter after the underscore
            .replace(/_+([^_]|$)/g, toUpperCase);
}
```

Above example would produce (try by copying and pasting it in your browser console) always `firstName`, given the following inputs:

```
asCamelCase("FirstName");   // firstName
asCamelCase("FIRST_NAME");  // firstName
asCamelCase("first_name");  // firstName
```

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code to change the  `key` in Dictionary to CamelCase

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var dataList = GetDataFromPostgresql();
        var newDataList = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (var data in dataList)
        {
            var newData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var key in data.Keys)
            {
                var newKey = "";

                var value = data[key];

                var index = key.IndexOf('_');

                if(index < 0)//for GetDataFromMssql()
                {
                    newKey = Char.ToLowerInvariant(key[0]) + key.Substring(1);
                }else
                {
                    newKey = key.ToLowerInvariant().Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                    newKey = newKey.Replace(newKey[index], Char.ToUpperInvariant(newKey[index]));
                }


                newData.Add(newKey, value);
            }

            newDataList.Add(newData);
        }
        return Ok(newDataList);
    }
```

If you have complex value like `"first_name_hello_test"`, you could use below workaround:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var dataList = GetDataFromPostgresql();
        var newDataList = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (var data in dataList)
        {
            var newData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var key in data.Keys)
            {
                var newKey = "";

                var value = data[key];

                var indexList = new List<int>();
                var index = key.IndexOf('_');

                if (index < 0)
                {
                    newKey = Char.ToLowerInvariant(key[0]) + key.Substring(1);

                }else
                {
                    while (index >= 0)
                    {
                        indexList.Add(index);
                        index = key.IndexOf('_', index + 1);
                    }
                    newKey = key.ToLowerInvariant();
                    foreach(var i in indexList)
                    {
                        newKey = newKey.Replace(newKey[i+1], Char.ToUpperInvariant(newKey[i+1]));
                    }
                    newKey = newKey.Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);

                }


                newData.Add(newKey, value);
            }

            newDataList.Add(newData);
        }
        return Ok(newDataList);
    }
```